# How to mod_rewrite a number in url to a name

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a database where I'm picking up information and in this case

```
user 1023 = madonna
```

I'm having today an url which is:

```
http://domain.com/welcome.php?p=user&xoxo=1023
```

and I would like to have the url like this instead

```
http://domain.com/user/madonna
```

Comment: Rules cannot query your database.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this htaccess

Before that you should backup your original htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^xoxo=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.site/user/madonna [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done for a *arbitrary* number mapping, such as one defined in a database. Instead the application itself should handle the name <-> ID/number processing in this case.

The rewrite (if used) would *only* be used turn something like `/user/madonna` into `/welcome.php?user=madonna`; likewise the 'pretty URL' should be generated by the application itself using the already-available username.

tldr; *The application - not mod_rewrite - is responsible for transformation to/from the username (ie. "madonna") and the corresponding user ID (ie. 1023).*

---

Anyway, a slightly different approach is to follow what StackOverflow does for URLs; it encodes the ID *and* a 'friendly' portion.

For instance a 'friendly question URL' is `http//../questions/$id/$title` while the only *relevant* portion of the URL is `http://../questions/$id` as the title portion is entirely irrelevant to locating the correct question. Similarly, my profile is `http://../users/2864740/user2864740` but my username is irrelevant to processing the query and `http://../users/2864740` is sufficient to access my profile.

*Note:* StackOverflow will immediately redirect to the correct-full-friendly-URL if the 'friendly' portion does not match the item referenced by ID; this is especially important for something like user accounts to mitigate spoofing. It also ensures the 'correct' URL is propagated after a title/username change.

In context of the question this would mean the pretty URL is `http://domain.com/user/1025/madonna` were the ID is already available and easily transformed to a query parameter.